# SQL Server factors that can contribute to high CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to figure out or enlist factors that contribute to persistent high CPU utilization related to SQL Server

Here are few that I came up with

a) Compilation or Frequent Recompilation of stored procs or queries

b) Poor performing queries that perform huge sort or ended up using Hash Join

c) Parallelism (multiple threads are span so it can keep CPU busy)

d) Looping construct in T-SQL for e.g. WHILE Loop or use of CURSOR

e) Missing or inappropriate indexes that leads to table scan

What are other SQL server operations can lead for a high CPU use?

Comment: The missing or inappropriate indexes really doesn't affect CPU, it's almost exclusively disk I/O.  Also, looping constructs are not especially CPU intensive unless the calculations in them are complex.

Comment: Missing statistics that can really screw with parallelism

Comment: I meant missing or out-of-date statistics.

Comment: one more thing parameter sniffing... just found out

Answer (score 1):

**Data compression** is relatively CPU-intensive.  **Encryption** is another operation that can cause high CPU utilization.

Comment: Transperent data encryption... good one as well as cell level encryption

Comment: I will also add backup compression

Answer (score 1):

Use of scalar user-defined functions uses a lot more CPU than you might think.

Comment: Only if you use them in the wrong place. :-)

Comment: Aaron, did  you mean if you use UDF which access table data.. instead of performing some calculatios correct me?

Comment: Right, the CPU usage will be directly related to the number of rows and/or executions. If the UDF is executed 80,000 times because you've applied it in the SELECT list, each invocation won't use a lot of CPU but the sum total will. On the other hand, if your procedure starts out with `DECLARE @x = dbo.SomeFunc();`, or even in a lot of scenarios where it's part of the query, the function is only going to be called once, so you're not going to see high CPU usage from that (unless the function also does or causes some of the other things from the question).

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed. I guess I'm used the the C# world where a function isn't that expensive if you don't call it a lot :) Do you think they will ever make inline scalar UDFs?

Comment: At some point. I complained to them that they're referenced (once) in Books Online, but never again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=sql.105).aspx (and going all the way back to the 2005 version) says: "For an inline scalar function, there is no function body; the scalar value is the result of a single statement." Of course they have yet to ship such a thing.

Comment: here is the connect item we can vote http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273443/the-scalar-expression-function-would-speed-performance-while-keeping-the-benefits-of-functions

Comment: Also note that the "Types of Functions" document was completely removed from SQL Server 2012 Books Online, some time after I pointed this out (that topic *did* exist in April), but the text still seems to have been copied to a section of the "User-Defined Functions" topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx